# HTTP ERROR 405 | ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC | slash problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, http-status-code-405, slash

I need some help right there.

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC, all is going well, but not for a specific action.

I have several pages : Start -> Index -> AddUser.

I navigate between my pages thanks to `<button>`s.

**Index.cshtml** :

```html
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AddUser" asp-route-GB="@ViewBag.GB">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
</form>
```

**HomeController.cs** :

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Start(string GB) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(GB)) {
    return RedirectPermanent("Error");
  }
  else {
    return View();
  }
}
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string GB) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(GB)) {
    return RedirectPermanent("Error");
  }
  else {
    return View();
  }
}
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddUser(string GB) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(GB)) {
    return RedirectPermanent("Error");
  }
  else {
    return View();
  }
}
public ActionResult Error() {
  return View();
}
```

**URL results :**

`https://localhost:XXXXX/Home/Start?GB=1` -> Is going well.

`https://localhost:XXXXX/Home/Index?GB=1` -> Is going well.

`https://localhost:XXXXX/Home/AddUser?GB=1` -> **HTTP ERROR 405**

BUT ! If I add a slash to this last one :
`https://localhost:XXXXX/Home/AddUser/?GB=1` -> Is going well.

What is going on ? I don't want to add a slash on my browser to make it work...

Comment: can you show your AddUser action pls?

Comment: Do you have multiple AddUser* routes? If so try experimenting by renaming the route name and check why the router can't identify this route correctly. You could make it more explicit by adding the route attribute [HttpGet("AddUser?GB={gb})]" if you didn't do that already.

But with the information provided there is no way to answer why the route is not uniquely matched to an action.

Comment: Now you got my entire HomeController.cs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it, basically

- `<a>` supports `[HttpGet]`
- `<button>` + `<form>` supports `[HttpPost]`

**If you want to use `[HttpGet]` then :**

```html
<a class="btn btn-success" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AddUser" asp-route-GB="@ViewBag.GB">
    Next Step
</a>
```

**If you want to use `[HttpPost]` then :**

```html
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AddUser" asp-route-GB="@ViewBag.GB">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Next Step</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing for while add or create api, it must be POST type not GET.
Try to use `[HttpPost]` attribute. It might solve your issue.

Comment: Well, actually, it works in fact. But I don't get it, I'm not "posting" anything, I just want to GET a page. Just like Index or Start...